# How can I repair WU after a failed forced Win10 upgrade on Optiplex 780?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Weeks ago, despite my best efforts to prevent it, (GWX Control), Microsoft decided to force a Windows 10 upgrade on my Optiplex 780 system.  It failed. The system runs Windows 7 Professioinal SP1.

Now every time I start Windows Update I am greeted with a bright red banner telling me that the Windows 10 upgrade failed and it gives one of those useless error numbers.

Dell is no help - they simply respond that the 780 was never tested for Win10 and suggest I reformat and reinstall.  Not gonna happen.

My question is:  Is there a known way I can repair Windows Update on this system?

Comment: Has it been 5 months?  Well, right at the end of the free period they found a way to override my GWX controls and pushed it overnight.  What a mess.  I have run system cleanup, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right at the end of the free period they found a way to override my GWX controls and shoved the upgrade on me overnight.

The red banner in Windows Update telling me that Win10 failed is annoying, for sure.

But I just found a workaround - I clicked on Check for Updates and it got the several rollups all at once.  After a reboot to finish the installs it seems fine.  (So now I am making an image backup)

I don't mind a little more hands-on as long as it works.  I suppose I can tolerate the red banner telling me Win10 failed.

I was really hoping someone could tell me how to clean it up.

Not every question gets a satisfactory answer here, I know.

Cheers.

Comment: I have run the cleanup tool but it still gives me the red flag whenever I start WU.  I just click on Check for Updates and then all is well.  It is an annoyance but I don't know how to make it quit telling me that it failed.